# Is it OK to continue to work a job after accepting an offer from a different company

Tags: professionalism, interviewing

I am interviewing for a position out of state.  My family situation is such that I won't be able to take the job (if offered) for about 2 months.  Is it acceptable to continue to work my current job for those 2 months, then give my notice?

Comment: You truly need to ask the company which offers you the job. We cannot answer the question _Is it acceptable to continue to work my current job ... ?_

Answer (score 6):

You do the following steps: First, you read your contract and find out how much notice you have to give. Second, you find a new position, and tell the company when you can start and how much notice you have to give. Third, you sign a contract with a start date far enough away that you can give notice. Fourth, you give notice just the right time before you start your new job.

So if you can't move to a new job for two months, and you need to give two weeks notice, then you sign a contract to start in two months time, and two weeks before the starting date you give notice to the old company.

Comment: Spot on. Note that in the US or in other countries where short notice periods (weeks rather than months) are common you should probably inform the company during or after the first interview. Two months generally won't be a problem for non-entry-level positions but if they're trying to fast-track the process neither you nor they will want to find out at the offer stage. And keep in mind that the interview process itself can take months so it might not even be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

It will help if you mentioned which country you are located as notice customs vary.

But in the US, my understanding is that it would be a standard 2 week notice from an employee who wishes to quit/resign.

This said, if your position requires a significant amount of training to get a replacement up to speed, then more would be needed.

Note, interviewing =/= job in hand. So if you give your notice and there is no actual job waiting for you. Then you will be hard pressed to return to your old position.

> tldr: You can, but you need to be aware of your timing and whether or
>   not you have a job to go to after you seperate.